# PHP mongodb get Inserted and updated ID's?

Tags: php, mongodb

i am trying to get Insert ID or update ID while update or insert a record in Mongodb Collection  :

The Error i am getting is :

```
Fatal error :  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\UpdateResult::getUpsertedIds() in **/***/****.php:64
Stack trace:
```

The code is inserting or updating successfully , but i am not able to get the effected raw ID :

```
$collection = $this->api->MDB->getCollection("verify_code", $db_name = "auth")->email;
                    
                $collection->createIndex(
                        array( "email" => 1 ),
                        array( "unique" => true )
                );
                    
                $document = array("email" => $data['email'],
                                  "code" => 232);
                
                $result = $collection->updateOne(
                    array("email" => $document["email"]),
                    array('$set' => $document,'$setOnInsert' => ['created_at' => time()]),
                    array("upsert" => true)
                );
                
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $result->getUpsertedIds();
                print_r($result);
```

is it possible to get the effected raw ID ? or i should do another query for it

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getUpsertedIds` method in `MongoDB\UpdateResult`, but instead there is `getUpsertedId` which should return `null` when updating many documents [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/9f8eac1400fdb11d9a427d636689943a48447167/src/UpdateResult.php). You can get the documents matched in `updateOne` call via [find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/) when `updateOne` hasn't changed the document attributes in match criteria.